# UEFI Bootable USB Drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 64gb flash drive that I want to boot from in Legacy mode so I can install Ubuntu on my 3Tb Hard drive but the flash drive keeps booting into EFI mode and causing the install to get stuck at Detecting System Files. Sorry about the run on sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when bootable USB are not created properly (if you search "Ubuntu installation stuck at Detecting Files System" you will find many related questions in this forum or in Ubuntuforums website).

I recommend you to follow the **official** guidelines about creating a bootable USB from Windows. See them [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). In particular, it is always recommended to **verity** the Ubuntu file. Again, official information about how to do this is available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify).